# Python Selenium Chrome Not Running Headless

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I'm currently writing a program in which I'm connecting to chrome. I would like to make this process without a new chrome window popping up every time. I know that `--headless` makes chrome run silently, but my current code is not working; it is still opening up chrome tabs.

Current Code:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chrome_options)
```

What am I doing wrong or what do I need to add?

Comment: Why is it "not working"? What happens when you run it?

Comment: @PedrovonHertwig fixed my question. Chrome is still opening tabs. I would like it to not open tabs/run headless.

Comment: Headless mode only available on Chrome 59 Mac OS / linux only for now, check whether your environment has met this requirement to gain advantage of headless mode

Comment: It works if you use `headless` instead of `--headless`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux one alternate solution to run the browser in headless mode is to use pyvirtual display.
First install xvfb and pyvirtual display:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb xserver-xephyr

sudo pip install pyvirtualdisplay
```

The code will be:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
import webdriver
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
```